# How to implement once.Do with singelton and Cloud Function

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

On refactoring singleton pattern with once.Do and Cloud Functions, I got caught in a case where service creation fails due to config error, which can be rectified by reuploading valid config, but when used with once.Do you would have to also redeploy Cloud Functions.

I wonder if there is a way to avoid CF redeployment or a different way of implementing the singleton pattern with once.Do.

Original singleton implementation:

```
var srv Service

//Singleton returns service
func Singleton(ctx context.Context) (Service, error) {
    if srv != nil {
        return srv, nil
    }
    config, err := NewConfig(ctx, shared.URL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    srv, err = New(ctx, config)
    return srv, err
}
```

refactored with run once

```
var once sync.Once

//Singleton returns service
func Singleton(ctx context.Context) (Service, error) {
    var err error
    onceBody := func() {
        srv, err =  newService(ctx)
    }
    once.Do(onceBody)
    return srv, err
}
func newService(ctx context.Context) (Service, error) {
    var config *Config
    if  config, err = NewConfig(ctx, shared.URL); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return  New(ctx, config)
}
```

Comment: Overwrite the `once` value with a new `sync.Once` when you want to let it run again.

Comment: I knew it is simple, tnx that will work